# Table rows not on the screen but still part of the table in Cypress test?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress

In my app, there is a table of companies & the countries they are from.

I have a filter button where users enter a country name & only companies associated with the selected country are displayed on the table.

When manually testing, the table is updated as expected.
(Example: If I select Belgium, only Belgian companies are displayed).

However when I run my Cypress test to validate that only Belgium companies are displaying, I am facing an issue.

Rather than just Belgium companies being logged, all the companies are still being logged.

I think that the table might still be returning rows even if `visibility:hidden` or something like that.

Is there a way to check only which rows are appearing / visible to users?

Here is my current test code:

```
cy.get('tr td:nth-child(6)').each(($el) => {
    const country = $el.text()
    cy.log(country)
})
```

Here is the HTML table, as you can see only Belgium is appearing, but in my Cypress logs several other countries are being logged too.

```
<table role="grid" tabindex="0" aria-activedescendant="grid_active_cell">
   <colgroup>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
   </colgroup>
   <tbody role="rowgroup">
      <tr data-uid="7176cc62-7bce-438a-a9b8-d9ffbebbb079" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=547428&amp;meetingId=780865" securityid="547428" aria-label="Open votes for Aedifica NV">Aedifica NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-03-29</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="adb62a46-91bd-4c5c-8a8f-336b9b9d48ae" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31449&amp;meetingId=802714" securityid="31449" aria-label="Open votes for Ageas SA/NV">Ageas SA/NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-16</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="e54e2f6b-7082-4b5f-a87d-aab2f2dfae0d" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31369&amp;meetingId=794551" securityid="31369" aria-label="Open votes for Agfa-Gevaert">Agfa-Gevaert</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-08</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="fba9396a-6165-462e-8dad-4a805565d033" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=530179&amp;meetingId=871207" securityid="530179" aria-label="Open votes for Anheuser-Busch In Bev SA/NV">Anheuser-Busch In Bev SA/NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-04-24</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 68381F409</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="5cd4e16e-91f5-4a19-aa67-97e4ad88ccdc" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31379&amp;meetingId=872501" securityid="31379" aria-label="Open votes for Barco NV">Barco NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-04-25</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 904214103</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">3 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="6712784a-63ad-42e7-9c86-d829c2f19872" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=46875&amp;meetingId=874473" securityid="46875" aria-label="Open votes for Befimmo">Befimmo</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-04-30</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 40434L105</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="c7d0b0c2-153a-4ea0-b5da-b8916f035a77" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=617304&amp;meetingId=797798" securityid="617304" aria-label="Open votes for Bpost S.A. / N.V">Bpost S.A. / N.V</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-09</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="0e6353c7-c8d2-48cd-b9d7-d0ec8d82d7e0" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=46876&amp;meetingId=877447" securityid="46876" aria-label="Open votes for Cofinimmo">Cofinimmo</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-08</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 89469A104</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="3ac0ea89-ff29-48f4-ac07-115c836a4849" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31414&amp;meetingId=832086" securityid="31414" aria-label="Open votes for Colruyt">Colruyt</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-10-10</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 920437100</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">3 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="c0c939ea-eea3-4667-8e27-e70755197c28" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31461&amp;meetingId=887530" securityid="31461" aria-label="Open votes for D`leteren">D`leteren</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-06-06</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 48213W101</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="920d6ff4-e4d6-4b74-b8ce-e43248fe9ee6" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31438&amp;meetingId=803697" securityid="31438" aria-label="Open votes for Econocom Group SA">Econocom Group SA</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-15</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="efae0205-430a-41f8-ad1b-ab5063d436c9" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=53885&amp;meetingId=881928" securityid="53885" aria-label="Open votes for Elia System Operator S.A. N.V.">Elia System Operator S.A. N.V.</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-21</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 337932107</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="427a4823-25ce-4455-afa6-8a0746d5cd0a" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31453&amp;meetingId=893818" securityid="31453" aria-label="Open votes for GIMV">GIMV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-06-26</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 29476L107</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="2960be45-8f3f-4483-ac4b-6241ecddfcd7" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31456&amp;meetingId=871202" securityid="31456" aria-label="Open votes for Groupe Bruxelles Lambert (New)">Groupe Bruxelles Lambert (New)</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-04-23</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 68381F409</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="961af823-2dee-44b4-bba6-7f3ff9b67034" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31476&amp;meetingId=874474" securityid="31476" aria-label="Open votes for KBC Group SA NV">KBC Group SA NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-02</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 191098102</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">3 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="e57e6b91-5c84-40a2-a964-081142940c26" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=546950&amp;meetingId=882568" securityid="546950" aria-label="Open votes for Montea.">Montea.</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-21</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: G96629103</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="d14ab9f3-4c41-499b-933e-bae4714750fd" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31384&amp;meetingId=894728" securityid="31384" aria-label="Open votes for NV Bekaert SA.">NV Bekaert SA.</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-07-03</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 30063P105</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">3 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="bdae140f-eb93-4c08-92d6-9785ec413d15" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=49845&amp;meetingId=874475" securityid="49845" aria-label="Open votes for Orange Belgium">Orange Belgium</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-02</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 191098102</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="725711af-bd86-4f06-a244-22733629a7de" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31510&amp;meetingId=806189" securityid="31510" aria-label="Open votes for Recticel">Recticel</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-29</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Demo JPM</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="96493bf0-7a36-412f-845a-ed18b411f5ba" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31518&amp;meetingId=876013" securityid="31518" aria-label="Open votes for Sofina">Sofina</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2019-05-02</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 191098102</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="17830ced-72d1-4184-a997-d3e3045b6dab" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31521&amp;meetingId=801022" securityid="31521" aria-label="Open votes for Solvay SA">Solvay SA</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-05-08</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="e4bb468f-9916-4dbf-a988-4f94943ad7ea" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=526844&amp;meetingId=829671" securityid="526844" aria-label="Open votes for Telenet Group Hldgs NV">Telenet Group Hldgs NV</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-09-26</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 56585A102</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">2 Accounts</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr data-uid="c4049318-7acb-47be-bfd4-ba278ae112bc" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=31536&amp;meetingId=788586" securityid="31536" aria-label="Open votes for UCB SA">UCB SA</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-04-26</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="k-alt" data-uid="82460575-0341-403e-9e79-88b857dd3114" role="row">
         <td style="min-width:400px" class="" aria-describedby="3d440895-b13c-4ff0-8e1a-82b8a1b3d1fb" role="gridcell"><a href="https://viewpoint.glasslewis.com/WD/MeetingDetail/?siteId=DemoClient&amp;securityId=590115&amp;meetingId=796289" securityid="590115" aria-label="Open votes for Umicore">Umicore</a></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="13a8df51-aa83-4a15-8e5e-c3124c70253e" role="gridcell">2018-04-26</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="c6ea5971-693d-4460-a8b3-b3065c933fd3" role="gridcell"></td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="23342bdc-3661-428f-bc9b-704778ac2d80" role="gridcell">CUSIP9: 47103C357</td>
         <td style="min-width:120px" class="" aria-describedby="64d4fac8-d35d-4437-956b-9eecd847d5b0" role="gridcell">Acct 80</td>
         <td style="min-width:150px" class="" aria-describedby="abdb9d26-dbbc-409b-b0b6-5714bd6ab3d1" role="gridcell">Belgium</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

When I try the below answer, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: Hi @AlapanDas I've added the HTML now

Answer (score 0):

First we are searching for all `td` elements whose inner text is `Belgium`. Then once we have those elements, we will iterate over them using `each`. Then using `parent` we would be going to the `tr` for all the td's having Belgium. Then using `within` we would be scoping the query inside the specific row and then print the first `tr` element containing the name of the company. Something like:

```js
cy.get('td')
  .filter(':contains("Belgium")')
  .each(($ele) => {
    cy.wrap($ele)
      .parent('tr')
      .within(() => {
        cy.get('td')
          .eq(0)
          .invoke('text')
          .then((company) => {
            cy.log(company) //Prints the name of the companies in Belgium
          })
      })
  })
```

And, if applying the filter `Belgium` on your table, if you want to validate that only Belgium is displayed, you can do something like:

```js
cy.get('tr').each(($ele) => {
  cy.wrap($ele).within(() => {
    cy.get('td').eq(5).should('have.text', 'Belgium')
  })
})
```

Comment: But the point of my test is to filter the table so that it only shows companies related to Belgium. If we filter for all `td` elements whose inner text is `Belgium` we're not really tesitng the functionality

Comment: Didn't get your question, you want to apply filters on your webpage ?

Comment: Yes, so the user functionality that I'm testing is filtering the table so that only Belgium companies appear.

I then am writing a Cypress test to validate that only Belgium companies are now appearing.

But when I run my current test code, companies of all countries are being logged, even though just Belgium companies are appearing.

I think they may be hidden in the table but still referenced as part of the table.

Comment: So in your test you want to check that after applying filter only `Belgium` as a country should be displayed in the table and if any other country is displayed, the test should fail?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I have updated the answer

Comment: I've tried your answer, but it's still not picking up just the Belgium companies

Comment: To get the sixth element you have to use eq(5) because the index starts from 0.

Comment: Getting same error message when using 5

Comment: As per the html you have added I could see 6 `td` inside one `tr`. And assuming this structure is uniform meaning all your tr's have 6 td's. Then this code will work, I am 100% sure. Please make sure that you have saved the changes before running.

Comment: The structure is uniform, but it's still not working for some reason. There must be some special attributes assigned to this table